# No whitespaces or line breaks in HTML textarea

Tags: php, html, forms, utf-8, textarea

I have a html textarea that sends the text input to me by email. 
Problem is that the input from the textarea are sent/recieved as a continuous string without whitespaces or line breaks. 
UTF-8 characters are also ignored.

I've tried `str_replace(" ", &nbsp, $message)` in an attempt to change whitespaces into a html whitespace character, but no luck.

To fix make the textarea support UTF-8 I tried to put accept-charset="utf-8" in the form declaration, but no luck in that either.

I've also tried a couple of other solutions on the net, but got none working

Comment: are you sending html email ?

Comment: Is `&nbsp` a typo? Should be `&nbsp;`. Could you post more of your code? I can't think of an instance where all whitespace would be removed.

Comment: @Dagon I'm using the standard PHP mail() function. Not sure what format it sends the email in.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, it's a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: well that depends what headers you set, you really nee to pot some code in this question

Answer (score 0):

fast way to fix line breakes 
is

```
$yourtext = str_replace('\n','<br>',$yourtext);
```

Comment: Then the PHP function nl2br would be a better solution. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: str_replace('\n','<br>',$yourtext) unfortunately does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_replace(" ", '&nbsp;', $message)`

Comment: Its better to explain the code and why you think it works.

Comment: This puts &nbsp in place of the whitespaces. So "test test test" becomes "test&nbsptest&nbsptest" when I recieve the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Turns out it was `filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);` that was the culprit